# Offline installing libxml2-dev in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: package-management, offline

Hi I'm kinda new to Ubuntu and have a problem. I don't have any internet on my pc and wanto install the libxml2-dev package to my system. I've gotten hold of a .deb file which I can open with the Software Centre buuuut, when I do that I get an error: Dependency is not satisfiable: libicu-dev.
Here is the complete name of the .deb file I downloaded from LaunchPad site.
libxml2-dev_2.9.2+dfsg_1-3_amd64.deb
So can anyone help me install this package via .deb file format please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to a system with Internet access and download `libicu-dev`
via

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu-dev_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```

and install with

```
sudo dpkg -i libicu-dev_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
```

Then install the `libxml2-dev` package again

```
sudo dpkg -i libxml2-dev_2.9.2+dfsg1-3_amd64.deb
```

---

However, it may be that you still need more packages. Unfortunately I can not say that because I do not know what you have already installed. But I think the way forward is clear. **;)**

All packages are available [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). Search the packages for Vivid (`vivid` and/or `vivid-updates`) and download the 64-bit versions. Use an USB stick and use this stick in your desktop system.

Comment: If you have further problems, give me a comment =)

Comment: Ok that was thee fastest and only response I received in the past 2days. Thanks!!;) but as mentioned I don't have an internet connection on the desktop. Are there any official sites to download a tar package or deb file to install it manually?

Comment: The `wget` command download the deb file and all packages are available here http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: That was helpful thank you. Got the file and gona see now what happens. Can't thank you enough ey.

Comment: Ok now I have another dependency error. I need icu-devtools. Under which category will this package be?

Comment: Here: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/icu-devtools_52.1-8ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb

Comment: Thank you. Most probably gonna install this then get anothet dependency error but hope not. Tell me,,how do I get rhythmbox to play MP3s? It needs some kind of plugin and or encoder,,how to install this like I do with those library files? And where exactly to find these?. Its time consuming to install or update my ubuntu system in this way but for now its gotta do.

Comment: Sorry @GeneSmit, for this question you should ask a new question on AskUbuntu. The comments below an answer are the wrong place for that. :)

Comment: ok sorry for that. Will then first sort out my current question. Thank you.

Comment: SORTED!! Thanks A Lot A.B. I've now installed all those libs & installed my bz2 file which gave me errors regarding those libraries. Asked a new question about my rhythmbox plugin error. Would you check it out please.

Comment: Sure, give me a link

Comment: And an upvote for my answer here ;)

Comment: http://goo.gl/ycun44